# How to parse through JSON object in Python

Tags: python, json, google-geocoding-api

I know there are tons of this exact question on here but I can't find an answer.

I'm trying to use the [Google Maps API for Geocoding](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/geocodestrat) to go through a list of sloppy addresses, and get formatted addresses.

I have this exact code from the Google documentation:

```
import urllib2

address="1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA"
url="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=%s" % address

response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
jsongeocode = response.read()
```

It then says that `jsongeocode` is a JSON object. However, from what I've gathered from looking online is that this IS NOT a JSON object yet. **If i'm wrong here and it is a JSON object, how do I parse it?**

If I call `print(jsongeocode)` it prints what appears to be a JSON object with the proper attributes in my terminal.

So I try to convert the `jsongeocode` object to a JSON object:

```
jdata = json.load(jsongeocode)
```

This gives me this error:

```
AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'read'
```

**EDIT**

I've switched the json function call to `jdata = json.loads(jsongeocode)`, but now the error I get is this:

```
TypeError: The JSON Object must be str, not 'bytes'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works fine in Python 2. You just need to parse the JSON string returned by the API using `json.loads(jsongeocode)`.

The error message `TypeError: The JSON Object must be str, not 'bytes'` suggests to me that you are using Python 3. However, you are importing the `urllib2` module which is only present in Python 2. I'm not sure how you achieved that. Anyway, assuming Python 3:

```
import json
from urllib.request import urlopen

address="1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA"
url="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=%s" % address
response = urlopen(url)
json_byte_string = response.read()

>>> type(json_byte_string)
<class 'bytes'>
>>> jdata = json.loads(json_byte_string)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/json/__init__.py", line 312, in loads
    s.__class__.__name__))
TypeError: the JSON object must be str, not 'bytes'
```

So there is the exception that you have seen. The response contained in `json_byte_string` is a byte string - it is of class `bytes`, however, in Python 3 `json.loads()` expects a `str` which is a Unicode string. So you need to convert `json_byte_string` from a byte string to Unicode. To do that requires that you know the encoding of the byte string. Here I use UTF8 because that is what was specified in the `Content-Type` response header:

```
>>> response.headers['Content-Type']
'application/json; charset=UTF-8'

>>> json_string = str(json_byte_string, 'utf8')
>>> type(json_string)
<class 'str'>
```

Now it can be passed to `json.loads()`:

```
>>> jdata = json.loads(json_string)
>>> jdata
{'results': [{'types': ['street_address'], 'address_components': [{'types': ['street_number'], 'long_name': '1600', 'short_name': '1600'}, {'types': ['route'], 'long_name': 'Amphitheatre Parkway', 'short_name': 'Amphitheatre Pkwy'}, {'types': ['locality', 'political'], 'long_name': 'Mountain View', 'short_name': 'Mountain View'}, {'types': ['administrative_area_level_2', 'political'], 'long_name': 'Santa Clara County', 'short_name': 'Santa Clara County'}, {'types': ['administrative_area_level_1', 'political'], 'long_name': 'California', 'short_name': 'CA'}, {'types': ['country', 'political'], 'long_name': 'United States', 'short_name': 'US'}, {'types': ['postal_code'], 'long_name': '94043', 'short_name': '94043'}], 'formatted_address': '1600 Amphitheatre Parkway, Mountain View, CA 94043, USA', 'geometry': {'location_type': 'ROOFTOP', 'viewport': {'northeast': {'lng': -122.0828811197085, 'lat': 37.4236854802915}, 'southwest': {'lng': -122.0855790802915, 'lat': 37.4209875197085}}, 'location': {'lng': -122.0842301, 'lat': 37.4223365}}, 'place_id': 'ChIJ2eUgeAK6j4ARbn5u_wAGqWA'}], 'status': 'OK'}
```

And there you have the decoded JSON string as a dictionary. The formatted address is available as:

```
>>> jdata['results'][0]['formatted_address']
'1600 Amphitheatre Parkway, Mountain View, CA 94043, USA'
```

---

There is a better way to do this: use `requests`:

```
import requests

address="1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA"
url="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=%s" % address

r = requests.get(url)
jdata = r.json()

>>> jdata['results'][0]['formatted_address']
'1600 Amphitheatre Parkway, Mountain View, CA 94043, USA'
```

Much better!

Answer (score -2):

use

```
jsongeocode = str(response.read())
jdata = json.loads(jsongeocode)
```

`json.load()` is for file-like objects, as described here:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.load

Comment: Still not working. I think `json.loads()` is the proper function call, but I'm getting the same error.

Comment: I TAKE THAT BACK! It's a different error. I'll update my question

Comment: yea you'll need to convert to a string before, see update.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to call correctly now. However, it is now giving me `AttributeError: Expecting Value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)`. I am looking into that now.

Answer (score -2):

```
this is my jsongeocode:

 {
   "results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "1600",
               "short_name" : "1600",
               "types" : [ "street_number" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Amphitheatre Parkway",
               "short_name" : "Amphitheatre Pkwy",
               "types" : [ "route" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Mountain View",
               "short_name" : "Mountain View",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Santa Clara County",
               "short_name" : "Santa Clara County",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "California",
               "short_name" : "CA",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "United States",
               "short_name" : "US",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "94043",
               "short_name" : "94043",
               "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "1600 Amphitheatre Parkway, Mountain View, CA 94043, USA",
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 37.4223365,
               "lng" : -122.0842301
            },
            "location_type" : "ROOFTOP",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 37.4236854802915,
                  "lng" : -122.0828811197085
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 37.4209875197085,
                  "lng" : -122.0855790802915
               }
            }
         },
         "place_id" : "ChIJ2eUgeAK6j4ARbn5u_wAGqWA",
         "types" : [ "street_address" ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

you can find the difference

by the way:
you can send http request use Requests module like that:

```
import requests

address="1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA"
url="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=%s" % address

response = requests.get(url)
jsongeocode = response.text
```